# Read and print the content of sheet in a workbook - openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, unit-testing, pytest, openpyxl

I have a excel file which I opened in openpyxl and cleaned it and closed the work book, with the example code below:

```py
#filename is the name of the excel file used 
wb = load_workbook(filename)
sheet = wb.active

#I did some cleaning on the sheet.
#I closed the workbook

wb.close()
```

As a part of the unit test of this function I want to read the content of the sheet of this workbook so that I can write a assert statement for the unit test.

I tried to read with:

```py
sheet.read()
```

But it only prints and read the sheet name like

```py
Workbook <Sheet 1>
```

I know we can iterate over rows of the sheet and read the contents of each row or cell but it would be too complicated to store for a unit tests and then assert it with a expected value.

How can I simply read the whole content of the sheet.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel files are tricky. On what basis should two cell values be considered equal? What if they contain the same values, but one is bold? Or if they have the same formula, but different computed values?

There are lots of ways that cells can differ, but I think you're looking for [`Worksheet`'s `values`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.values) property:

> Produces all cell values in the worksheet, by row
>
> Type: generator

For example, you can generate a list of tuples by doing

```py
list(sheet.values)
```

For a worksheet containing

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | B1 | C1 |
| 2 | A2 | B2 | C2 |
| 3 | A3 | B3 | C3 |
| 4 | =SUM(1, 2, 3) |  |  |

this yields

```py
[('A1', 'B1', 'C1'),
 ('A2', 'B2', 'C2'),
 ('A3', 'B3', 'C3'),
 ('=SUM(1, 2, 3)', None, None)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much Chris. This works ! The only thing is in my sheet, one column is date column and the way it is printing the result of sheet.value is - datetime.datetime(2019, 1,1,0,0) instead of printing 01.01.2019. Any idea how that can be changed to just normal datetime value? Thanks

Comment: Well at that stage you just have a Python data structure. You can do whatever you want with it. An ugly one-liner might be something like `[[cell.strftime("%d.%m.%Y") if isinstance(cell, datetime) else cell for cell in row] for row in sheet.values]` instead of `list(sheet.values)`, but I'm not clear why you'd want to coerce these values to strings. `datetime` objects are much richer data structures. You could also do `[[str(cell) for cell in row] for row in sheet.values]` if you don't care about the exact string formatting.